# How to add new item to a list (L2) from another list (L1) when my L2 is a column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp

I have a principle list in SharePoint (L1), this list contains a bunch of columns, one of the columns is also in a lists (L2).

I would like to be able to add a new items to L2 from inside my principle list L1 when selecting an item => modify.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Power Automate flow to add new items to L2 when an item is modified in L1.

1. Select the trigger "**When an item is created or modified**".
   [image]
2. Select "**Create item**" as action. Configure the value of the column in List1 as the value of it in List2. In this example, "1" is a column that exists in both List1 and List2.
   [image]